# PDO error handling and storing errors in database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How would I go about getting PDO statements to generate a safe error message? I don't want the user to see the error message. I want them to get directed to a page that says a clean message, "Whoops something unexpected happened!". I would also like to log the errors in a database to review and catch errors others are generating.

I'm using PHP and MySQL.

I found that when you make your connection you can set your error handling like this.

```
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Anyone do anything like this before?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you asking us for a complete solution?

Comment: Just some general direction, like catch the errors using this, and then write them out to a log file, and redirect the users. I guess I don't know the best way to catch the errors. I don't really want to rewrite all my commands.

Comment: Have yoou reaad this? http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php The PHP manual, look into the catch and PDOException part

Comment: One of the problems with storing errors in a database is that connecting to a database is one of the things that can raise an error.

Comment: Yes I have read that. I'm a little confused by it, do I enable exceptions (as they are disabled by default), and then try and catch them?

Comment: you could assign them to a variable and then use the fwrite function of PHP to create a text file and store them there, this would avoid database connection.

Comment: @EricSietsema I left a more detailed outline of what I meant as an answer that might be of interest. X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is better to write your logs to a file, instead of a database. Especially since you want to log PDO errors, which indicate something is wrong with your database connection.

You can show the user a nice error page by catching your errors. You can redirect your users to your error page then, in case something went wrong.

Comment: How would I catch the errors? Do I need to rewrite all my commands in try-catch statements, or can I make some sort of function that will run whenever a pdo command is run on the database?

Comment: Yes, you would have to wrap all your functions inside try-catch statements, or at least the code that might result in an error. You cannot create a function that catches all your PDO errors, unless you want to extend PDO and override all PDO functions.

Answer (score 2):

So this is just a suggestion as I have never tried this but after thinking about it a bit I think it would be an interesting option to explore. As I am fairly new to PHP & PDO I'm sure there are other and better ways.

Perhaps you could try using the `try` function of PHP and then instead of echo'ing (if failed) the PDOException you could run another function that prints it to a text file. Something like.

```
<?php
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
    foreach($dbh->query('SELECT * from FOO') as $row) {
        print_r($row);
    }
    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $strFileName = 'whatever.txt';

    if(!is_writable($strFileName))
        die('Change permisions to ' . $strFileName);

    $handle = fopen($strFileName, 'a+');

    fwrite($handle, "\r" . $e->getMessage() . "\r");
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

This way you would avoid a DB connection (which is the problem I guess) but still save the error. 
You would perhaps want to omit the echo'd text after die within the if statement.

Comment: You know, PHP can to it all already. PHP can open a file. PHP can write a log. PHP can catch an error message. **ALL without making you write a line of code**

Comment: @YourCommonSense No I didn't, like I said in my post still learning :) Thanks for letting me know I'll read into it

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand that PDO do not generate a "safe" or "unsafe" error message. It does generate an error message. That's all. The rest is is the responsibility of site-wide PHP settings.

PDO is not the only source of errors. Why care of PDO errors only? Why not to handle ALL errors the same way?

Want errors logged? It's a matter of one PHP ini setting.
Want errors not to be displayed? It's a matter of one PHP ini setting.
Want generic error page to be shown? It's a matter of simple function that will handle all errors at once.

Everything can be done  proper and straight way, without wrapping every statement into try catch. Without writing into log manually. Without even single additional line of code.

You need to set up PHP error handling, not PDO.

And of course, it makes absolutely no sense in trying to store a database error in the same database that failed you right now. Errors have to go into error log on a live server and on screen - on a local development PC.

> Anyone do anything like this before?

Sure. Every single one of 1000000s sites in the world. The way described above.

Comment: Can you provide some code examples or links that show code examples of how you can log all php errors?

Comment: just `log_errors = on` in php.ini is all the code example you need